# Symfony2: Global configurable backend prefix for all bundles?

Tags: symfony, configuration, routes

I'm looking for a global configuration for a routing prefix. There are a number of different bundles and I need a path to the backend controllers.

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/post")
 */
class PostAdminController extends Controller {
}
```

When I configure it that way, I have to edit a lot of files, if the prefix should be changed. Is it possible, to use a variable or a filter?

```
/**
 * @Route("/%BACKEND_PREFIX%/post")
 */
class PostAdminController extends Controller {
}
```

Somewhere in configuration:

```
backend_prefix = admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I found a solution, but it seems working since version 2.1.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/service_container_parameters.html